# why the useForm in react returns the empty errors object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { FormField, Button } from "@nef/core";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { SubmitHandler, useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import * as yup from "yup";

import { updateMyInfo } from "../../../../api/api";
import AccountSetting from "..";
import PageMetadata from "../../../../components/page-metadata";
import useUser from "../../../../hooks/useUser";
import useAuth from "../../../../hooks/useAuth";

import styles from "./style.module.scss";

const formSchema = yup
  .object({
    current_password: yup.string().required("CAN'T BE BLANK"),
    password: yup.string().required("CAN'T BE BLANK"),
    password_confirmation: yup
      .string()
      .required("CAN'T BE BLANK")
      .oneOf([yup.ref("password")], "DOESN'T MATCH PASSWORD.")
  })
  .required();

type FormType = yup.InferType<typeof formSchema>;

const ResetPasswordForm = () => {
  const {
    handleSubmit,
    control,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(formSchema)
  });
  const { passwordExpired } = useUser();
  const { authenticatedUser, logout } = useAuth();
  const history = useHistory();

  const [passwordWasSuccessfullyChanged, setPasswordWasSuccessfullyChanged] =
    useState<boolean>(false);
  const [samlAccountWasMigrated, setSamlAccountWasMigrated] =
    useState<boolean>(false);

  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FormType> = async data => {
    const payload = {
      ...authenticatedUser,
      current_password: data.current_password,
      password: data.password,
      password_confirmation: data.password_confirmation
    };
    const { data: userData } = await updateMyInfo(payload);
    if (userData.okta_conflict) {
      setSamlAccountWasMigrated(true);
    } else {
      setPasswordWasSuccessfullyChanged(true);
    }
  };

  const redirectToSamlLogin = (samlLoginEmail = "") => {
    const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_LOGIN_HOST}/web/users/saml_login_strategy?email=${samlLoginEmail}`;
    window.location.replace(url);
  };

  const signoutAndPromptForLogin = async () => {
    await logout();
    setPasswordWasSuccessfullyChanged(false);
    history.push("/login");
  };

  return (
    <AccountSetting>
      <>
        <PageMetadata metadataKey="account" />
        <div className="account-page-header with-top-blue-line">
          {passwordExpired() ? "Your Password Has Expired" : "Change Password"}
        </div>
        <hr />
        {samlAccountWasMigrated && (
          <div className="quandl-grid-col-6">
            <h2 className="medium-header medium-header--subtle">
              Password Not Changed
            </h2>
            <p className="small-paragraph">
              Nasdaq Data Link is happy to announce we are migrating your
              account with Nasdaq's Signin. Our records indicate that you
              already have a Nasdaq User Account and thus you will need to login
              and manage your account through Nasdaq.
            </p>
            <div className="quandl-grid-col-6">
              <Button
                onClick={() => redirectToSamlLogin(authenticatedUser?.email)}
              >
                Login with OKTA
              </Button>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
        {passwordWasSuccessfullyChanged && (
          <>
            <h3 className={styles.passwordChanged}>Password changed</h3>
            <p className={styles.description}>
              Your password was successfully changed.
            </p>
            <p className={styles.description}>
              For your security, we have logged out all your user instances that
              used your old password, including this one.
            </p>
            <Button onClick={signoutAndPromptForLogin}>
              Please click here to log in again with your new password
            </Button>
          </>
        )}
        {!passwordWasSuccessfullyChanged && !samlAccountWasMigrated && (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(data => onSubmit(data))}>
            <Controller
              name="current_password"
              control={control}
              defaultValue=""
              render={({ field: { onChange, value, name } }) => (
                <FormField
                  id="currentPassword"
                  name={name}
                  value={value}
                  onChange={onChange}
                  label="OLD PASSWORD"
                  type="password"
                  placeholder="Type here..."
                  data-testid="resetForm_currentPassword"
                  invalid={!!errors.current_password}
                  feedback={errors.current_password?.message}
                />
              )}
            />
            <Controller
              name="password"
              control={control}
              defaultValue=""
              render={({ field: { onChange, value, name } }) => (
                <FormField
                  id="password"
                  name={name}
                  value={value}
                  onChange={onChange}
                  label="NEW PASSWORD"
                  type="password"
                  placeholder="Type here..."
                  data-testid="resstForm_password"
                  invalid={!!errors.password}
                  feedback={errors.password?.message}
                />
              )}
            />
            <Controller
              name="password_confirmation"
              control={control}
              defaultValue=""
              render={({ field: { onChange, value, name } }) => (
                <FormField
                  id="passwordComfirmation"
                  name={name}
                  value={value}
                  onChange={onChange}
                  label="COMFIRM NEW PASSWORD"
                  type="password"
                  placeholder="Type here..."
                  data-testid="resetForm_passwordConfirmation"
                  invalid={!!errors.password_confirmation}
                  feedback={errors.password_confirmation?.message}
                />
              )}
            />
            <Button
              block={true}
              type="submit"
              data-testid="resetForm_updatePassword"
            >
              UPDATE
            </Button>
          </form>
        )}
      </>
    </AccountSetting>
  );
};
export default ResetPasswordForm;
```

The above is the code which deal with the password reset, Just trying to use react-hook-form to do the error handling, however, there's no error message returning back after the validation response from backend? wondering who can help me to point out which part is not correct

userForm() has been used to control the form validation and post-validation

Comment: The library can't magically understand the errors coming back from your API. You need to handle the errors coming back from the server and assign them to the fields using https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/seterror